# Excel : calculate a column only

Tags: excel

How can I select a column from a cell in Excel, and then calculate this column only ? I know only SHIFT + F9 that calculates te whole sheet, and F9 that calculates the whole workbook.

Thank you guys ;)

Comment: See this excellent write up by [Charles Williams on book/sheet/range calcuation](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsg.htm)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with only standard Excel (does anybody have a good tip?).

You can create a simple macro that will do it for you:

```
Sub Recalc()
Selection.Calculate
End Sub
```

And assign a shortcut to it. This will recalculate the selection only.